# How do to show path with friendly_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

Note that `User` has many `Photos`. I'm using the friendly_id gem to generate a slug for photos. This is my Photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :photo_by_author, :use => :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    title_changed?
  end

  def photo_by_author
    "#{title} by #{user_id}"
  end

  belongs_to :user
end
```

My path is `profilename/photos/title`, this is my routes.rb

```
scope ':profile_name' do
  resources :photos
end
```

In my controller, I'm doing `@photo = Photo.all`.

I'm trying this but isn't working: `<a href="<%= photo %>">`

How can I do the photos#show path??

Comment: Did you try: <a href="<%= photo_path(@photo) %>">

Comment: display this error: `missing required keys: [:id, :profile_name]`

Comment: What about  <a href="<%= photo_path(:id => @photo.id, :profile_name => @photo.profile_name) %>"> . If profile_name is an attribute of photo.

Comment: in this case the route is `/profilename/photos/5848` the end is ID, not the slug

Comment: I see. You could do @photo.slug. But that's weird, you should be able to generate a path just with the bare record '@photo' right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Link_To**

Firstly, you shouldn't be trying to populate a "naked" `<a>` with your ruby variable - you need to use the [`<%= link_to %>` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
<%= link_to photo.title, photo_path(photo) %>
```

The problem is your *scope*, especially considering this scope is used to determine a variable. I believe the issue is that since Rails expects a variable from this scope, it will not be able to process any of the links without having it

The simple way to resolve that error, as mentioned in the comments,is to populate the route with both values:

```
<%= link_to photo.title, photo_path(profile_name, photo) %> #-> photo & profile_name need to be declared
```

You'll want to look up a **rake routes** to make this work

---

**Friendly_ID**

If you want to populate the `friendly_id` `slug` values for this route, you'll need to do two things:

> 1. Pass the `profile_name` value as a "slug" (not ID)
> 2. Pass the `photo` object itself

I noticed in the comments, `Tiago Farias` posted a possible solution for you. If you want that to work with `friendly_id`, you'll need to pass the `photo` object **without** defining the `id` attribute (this will let `friendly_id` work its magic)

The next thing you need to consider is that since `:profile_name` is not tied to any "resource" (controller / model), `friendly_id` won't be able to populate the name / value that you'd expect. In this case, you need to set the value yourself (by defining it explicitly in your controller)

Answer (score 1):

Have you try

```
<% @photo.each do |photo| %>
<%= link_to photo.photo_by_author, photo %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<a href=<%= photo %>" ><%= Photo.first.photo_by_author %></a
>
```

inside the block

or in your console `rails c -s`

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
default_url_options[:host] = "localhost"
photo_url(Photo.first)
```